# Surjective maps with power sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $A =\{x, y, z\}$, is there a surjective map $f : (2^A\setminus A) \to A$?

The only thing I can think of is that this is not even a map given that $\emptyset$ does not map onto anything. Is that correct?

Comment: Why does A need to be subset of $2^A$ for a map to exist?

Comment: It doesn't need to be. There is a surjective map, check cardinalities. (I'm not sure why you are talking about $\emptyset$.)

Comment: Can you give me an example for a possible surjective map please?

Comment: By $A \subseteq 2^A$ do you mean $A$ is realised as subset with singleton sets. If yes, then the domain has 5 elements and the range has 3 elements. One can always define a surjective map by sending three elements to three images, rest can go anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $f : 2^A \setminus A \rightarrow A$ defined by
$$f(\emptyset)=x \qquad f(\lbrace x,y \rbrace)=y, \qquad f(\lbrace x,z \rbrace)=z,\qquad f(\lbrace y,z \rbrace)=x, \qquad f(\lbrace x,y,z \rbrace)=x$$
works.